# Tables do not exist error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write queries in oracle and I'm having trouble joining tables together. So I have two tables where one shows the movies a particular celebrity has starred in and the other shows the celebrity relationships. I have to find the movies where Tom Cruise co-starred with a celeb he is (or has been) in relationship with. So I have to join the starredin table along with the relationships table. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT S2.CELEB2 AS Costar,
S1.MOVIE
FROM S1.StarredIn,
S2.StarredIn,
Relationships
WHERE S1.CELEB = Relationships.CELEB1
AND S2.CELEB   = Relationships.CELEB2
AND S1.CELEB   = 'Tom Cruise';
```

Everytime I run this I get an error that says table or view does not exist except I have created both a table called StarredIn and a table called Relationships and I know I didn't mis-spell the table name during creation. So why do I keep getting that error?

Here's the statements to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Relationships (
  celeb1 VARCHAR(30), 
  celeb2 VARCHAR(30),
  started VARCHAR(15), 
  ended VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE StarredIn (
  celeb VARCHAR(30), 
  movie VARCHAR(100)
);
```

And then I have a bunch of insert statements.

Comment: Show your table names and fields, please.

Comment: Ok I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

If it was your intent to apply the alias of 'S1' to table 'StarredIn' it should look more like this:

```
From StarredIn S1, StarredIn S2, Relationships
```

Comment: It still says table or view does not exist. I updated my question to show how the tables are created.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with how are you giving alias name to the table.

Correct format for giving alias is

Table_name  alias_name.

Please try to run below query.

```
SELECT Relationships.CELEB2 AS Costar,
S1.MOVIE
FROM StarredIn  S1, StarredIn  S2 ,
Relationships
WHERE S1.CELEB = Relationships.CELEB1
AND S2.CELEB   = Relationships.CELEB2
AND S1.CELEB   = 'Tom Cruise';
```

Comment: I also updated my question which shows how the tables are created.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. It is really helpful. please confirm you are still getting error after using correct syntax for giving alias to table name.

Comment: Ok if I use your code then I get an error that says command not properly ended.

Comment: If I remove the "as" then it doesn't say that error however it goes back to saying table or view not found. I think it might be saying the relationship table cannot be found even though I know for a fact I created it.

Comment: I'm now getting the error which says table or view does not exist. This is strange because I tried to run a simpler query where I don't join any tables and just select from the Relationships table but it still says that table doesn't exist. What could be going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135632/discussion-between-tajinder-and-david-mah).

Answer (score 0):

`S1.StarredIn` means there is a table named `StarredIn` in schema `S1`. But you actually only want to give the table an alias name which is `StarredIn S1`.

Moreover you are using an outdated join syntax made redundant in 1992. Use explicit ANSI joins instead.

Then your database design or your access to it is strange. `StarredIn` contains an actor and a movie they starred in. `Relationships` relates two actors. You use this relation to relate two `StarredIn` records, however. So even if Tom Cruise and Katie Holmes were related and Tom Cruise played in Top Gun, that doesn't mean that Katie Holmes co-starred in that movie. You are making wrong assumptions in your query is seems.

As is, you don't need to join the `StarredIn` table again by the way, because the actor's name is in the `Relationships` table already.

The query can be properly written as:

```
select r.celeb2 as costar, s1.movie
from starredin s1
join relationships r on r.celeb1 = s1.celeb
where s1.celeb = 'Tom Cruise';
```

but as mentioned the results may not be what you are looking for.

I suppose you want to self-join `StarredIn` regardless of the `Relationships` so as to find other actors in the same movies.

```
select s2.celeb as costar, s1.movie
from starredin s1
join starredin s2 on s2.movie = s1.movie and s2.celeb <> s1.celeb
where s1.celeb = 'Tom Cruise'
order by s1.movie;
```